# Fullscreen games blacking the screen and running on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, monitor

It all started today, it had not happened to me before. Whenever I launch a game which is set to work fullscreen from startup, the game loads a couple frames in my primary monitor before freezing on it and switching the graphics/display to the second monitor.

[image: photo of both monitors]

If I start the game on the second monitor, the same happens.
The thing is that the game only detects input in the first monitor, as if the game was displaying on it.

I'm using Windows 10 Home, latest update if I had to guess because it always updates automatically.

Ask me anything if you want to know anything else!

Comment: What OS are you using? What does "could frames in mt" mean?

Comment: Windows 10 Home, and I'm so sorry ahout the mistyping, I had no idea I wrote that :/ I corrected it.

Comment: It could be Windows pushed through some 'improvements' in its latest update.

Comment: I have heard somewhere of someone who got the same issue some time ago, so I'm not sure it's that. Anyway, it feels really weird and it pretty much prevents me from playing games so I don't know what to do :/

Comment: Which monitor is your primary monitor in Windows? It looks like some elements of the game are present on the left monitor from what I can see as well. This is a weird one. What happens if you unplug the right monitor from the PC? Maybe try that, see what happens, then plug the monitor back in and see what happens again.

Comment: It works when unplugged but still happens again when I plug it back